# Encryption of data in an Ionic App

Tags: android, cordova, encryption

I was working on an Ionic app where the requirement was to store the data locally while the n/w is not available. So I was using PouchDB with sqlite to store the data locally and we need to make sure to send the data in an encrypted format when the n/w is available.

I know I should go for an assymetric encryption here but is there a cordova plugin, I shoud look at or should I look at developing one?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:

1. [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) with [sqlcipher adapter](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter)
2. [crypto-pouch](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/crypto-pouch)

The advantage of the first one is that encryption is done at the SQLite level rather than the JavaScript level, so it ought to be more performant. The disadvantage is that the SQLite Plugin is typically [not recommended for PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_in_the_browser) due to bugginess.

If the second one is performant enough for your use case, I'd say go with it.

Comment: Hi nlawson,
I am confused whether to use sqlcipher adapter  with the SQLite plugin or use it as a standalone plugin for sqlite db operations? I have gone through the documentation but I am unable to get started.